# How to check with PHP if a user likes my Facebook Page or not

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

Hi i want to show content after user click the  like button.
if he or she liked before it will show content no need like again.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

- It is no longer possible to get the liked status in a Page Tab
- It is no longer allowed to incentivize a Page Like according to the [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/)
- You could authorize a user with the `user_likes` permission, but you will not get it approved for like gating, so that´s not an option either

The main point is the second one. It´s not allowed to show content only when the user liked your Page. People should like something because they really do like it, not because they are forced to.